# Socket.io w/ node.js + nginx +mysql + php5-fpm Memory Leak?

Tags: nginx, mysql, node.js, memory-leak, socket.io

I have a Debian VPS running node.js socket.io server + nginx + mysql +php5-fpm and the socket server seems to freeze with no messages and no errors. I noticed that the memory usage grows over time but can't seem to find the reason.
I kept track of memory usage with 'top' command and that's what I found, but the memory didn't increase while I was checking.

> top - 09:31:08 up 10 days, 13:07,  2 users,  load average: 0.24, 0.43, 0.41
>   Tasks:  47 total,   1 running,  46 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
>   %Cpu(s): 14.5 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 83.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
>   KiB Mem:   2097152 total,   857692 used,  1239460 free,        0 buffers
>   KiB Swap:   524288 total,    22772 used,   501516 free,   482564 cached
>
> PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
>
> 13585 root      20   0  972m 259m  10m S  16.6 12.7   3:28.32 node
>
> 4702 mysql     20   0  529m  81m 8032 S  15.6  4.0 114:48.94 mysqld
>
> 13681 www-data  20   0  141m 7812 4428 S   0.3  0.4   0:00.99 php5-fpm
>
> 13683 www-data  20   0  141m 7560 4440 S   0.0  0.4   0:00.35 php5-fpm
>
> 13682 www-data  20   0  141m 6340 3336 S   0.3  0.3   0:00.40 php5-fpm
>
> 13375 root      20   0 71232 3632 2812 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.09 sshd
>
> 13359 root      20   0 71232 3624 2808 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.05 sshd
>
> 1590 bind      20   0  194m 3548 1876 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.21 named
>
> 3196 root      20   0 99.7m 2880 2340 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.40 smbd
>
> 3198 root      20   0 99.7m 2864 2364 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.40 smbd
>
> 24840 root      20   0 99.7m 2848 2396 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.89 smbd
>
> 13361 root      20   0 17888 2064 1512 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 bash
>
> 13377 root      20   0 17888 2060 1512 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 bash
>
> 2394 root      20   0  138m 1796  336 S   0.0  0.1   0:26.30 php5-fpm
>
> 2374 www-data  20   0 80476 1636  688 S   0.0  0.1  10:05.99 nginx
>
> 2375 www-data  20   0 80556 1628  688 S   0.0  0.1  10:11.15 nginx
>
> 13680 root      20   0 21600 1468 1068 R   0.0  0.1   0:00.15 top
>
> 2538 root      20   0 99928 1436 1136 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.81 smbd
>
> 1623 root      20   0  109m 1284  600 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.69 rsyslogd
>
> 2409 root      20   0 69760 1196  956 S   0.0  0.1   2:51.99 nmbd
>
> 2680 root      20   0 21784 1176  660 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.32 screen
>
> 13365 root      20   0 21556 1168  920 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 screen
>
> 13381 root      20   0 21556 1168  920 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 screen
>
> 2681 root      20   0 17908 1108  820 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 bash
>
> 2718 root      20   0 17908 1076  788 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.14 bash
>
> 2717 root      20   0 21788 1036  628 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.21 screen
>
> 1 root      20   0 30172  984  488 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.18 init
>
> 4362 root      20   0  4136  720  580 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 mysqld_safe
>
> 1727 root      20   0 57828  716  464 S   0.0  0.0   0:21.72 sendmail-mta
>
> 4703 root      20   0  4044  676  572 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 logger
>
> 1520 root      20   0 18928  456  328 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.84 rpcbind
>
> 2644 root      20   0 98.1m  448  292 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 smbd
>
> 1768 root      20   0 49892  376  260 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.09 sshd
>
> 2373 root      20   0 78372  336  136 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 nginx
>
> 1842 root      20   0 18836  216  140 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.20 cron

Since I'm new to those things I don't know where I'm messing things up, and I noticed that theres 3 php5-fpm processes as well as 3 nginx's.
I'm not sure what to do, and how to stop memory leak, and most important how to track it down because while I stand watching the 'top' results, nothing shows memory growing.

Comment: What memory leak are you referring to? It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: The server simply freezes after certain amount of time working, it just stops sending and receiving "emits". http://prntscr.com/9x9ch8 Here's the graphic for RAM use in my VPS